# Does ZFC allow self-reference?

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory

I heard that, "ZFC theory doesn't allow self-reference."

But I don't know exactly what it means. As we can see in the proof of Godel's incompleteness theorem, we can use method of "Diagonalization" and we can make a self-reference sentence in ZFC.

It means,

P : a statement mentioning a statement whose Godel number is i

and by diagonalization technique, when P's Godel number is i, P can be a self-reference sentence.

What's the meaning of "ZFC theory doesn't allow self-reference."

Comment: I don't think that it is possible to say anything without more context about the quote. There's no way to tell what it is supposed to mean based on the information provided.

Comment: I agree with Carl. It might have something to do with what you say, or it might simply be referring to the axiom of foundation. Or it might be clever-sounding nonsense. No way to know without knowing who said it and why.

Comment: Thank you @CarlMummert and MJD, when I discuss with a math graduate student with a problem, when I saying, "blah blah... if P is .. f(P) and..." he stopped me and advice me that "ZFC theory doesn't allow self-reference." So I siad to him about diagonalization method and he answered to me that diagonalization method does not always work. I thought diagonalization can work always. It makes me confusion.

Comment: See Rautenberg, [On the theory of self reference,](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-1-4419-1221-3_7), esp. the final section 7.7, Modal operators in ZFC. It is strange that this question was closed. Perhaps some of those who voted to close are not aware that there are rigorous theories of self-reference (e.g. via modal logic).

Comment: @HoCheol SHIN: you can improve the question by explaining exactly the sort of diagonalization you would like to do - then others could explain why it does or does not work. The issue with the question as it is written is that it is too vague to tell what you are trying to ask.

Comment: @MathGems Thank you for good and appropriate information. you gave me the answer what I want.